# StatsModels: Why do we have to fit a model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

In StatsModels (and other libraries like scikit-learn), we first have to create a model:

```py
model = sm.OLS(y, x)
```

and then fit it:

```py
results = model.fit()
```

Why are these two separate steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason why `fit`is a separate method can be seen from the arguments in `fit`. We create a specific model only once but we might want to or we might have to call `fit` several times.

One example are problems in optimization where we need to try out different optimizers or starting values before reaching convergence, or realizing that the model is not appropriate for the data and a regular optimum does not exist.

Another option that is available as `fit` argument are different `cov_type`s, those are different methods for computing the standard errors of the parameter estimates.

Another reason is that several models have now several `fit` methods that are not available through the regular `fit` method. Examples are `fit_regularized` for penalized estimation and `fit_constrained` for estimation under linear constraints on parameters. In these models we are not required to call the usual `fit` method.

More general question: Why does statsmodels use this complex class hierarchy and multitude of methods instead of putting everything in functions?

The main reasons are modularity, code reusability and lazy evaluation.

Answer (score -1):

`fit()` is a method of the class that represents the model. First you create an object from the class (`sm.OLS` here), and then you call the method `fit()` from that class.

The class has often times other methods such as `score`, `predict`, ...